# How many small fluid items are allowed in hand-luggage in European flight?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

I would like to carry nasal gels, saline for nebulizer and hand cream from Baltics to Sweden. 
I am thinking how many I can have in the transport. 
The flight carrier is AirBaltics. 
Example of fluid items which I would like to have in hand-luggage

- 3 x 25 mL nasal gels
- 10 x 10 mL saline containers
- 5x Bepathen hand cream - 50 or 100 mL (much cheaper in Baltics than Sweden)
- 5x Bepathen normal - 50 mL (much cheaper in Baltics than Sweden)

Volume of each fluid item: max 100 mL

Comment: `3*25+10*10+5x50+5x50=675`: may work if your are good at tetris; `3*25+10*10+5x100+5x50=925`: I doubt that you are this good at tetris

Comment: You need them all in your carry on ? can't you put some in your check in lugage ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take as many containers as fit well in a one liter recloseable plastic bag, as long as each container is 100 ml or less.

How many that is depends on the shapes and sizes of containers more than on the content.

Most useful plastic bags which are one liter are marked as such on the outside of the packaging, take one of those with you when shopping.
(And take away any cardboard and such to make the packagings as small as you can.)

You can almost always find information like this on the site of the airport you leave from. I looked at [the information for Riga.](http://www.riga-airport.com/en/main/passengers/useful-information/aviation-security-requirements/conditions-of-carriage-of-liquids-in-cabin-baggage)

Comment: Do you know if this is a general pratice in EU? - - Thank you for your fast answer!

Comment: It is not only general practice in the EU but also in North America and other parts of the world.

Comment: Do you know if you get such a plastic bag (1 L) free of charge in most airports? - - I will try to get one before my flight but cannot ensure if I can find one today.

Comment: You can get them for free on some airports, can buy them on others, but no airport has ever guarantied me they always have them. I have not been in the Baltics nor in Swedish airports.

Comment: If the liquids are medical and needed during or shortly after the flight they might be carried extra on the one liter bag.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about AirBaltics, but many low-costers allow to check-in your hand luggage (Norwegian and RyanAir asked me if I'd like to, AirBaltics didn't but I've seen a cart with tagged hand luggage that was later put in the plane).

So if you are OK with some waiting after landing, you can check-in you hand luggage, in which case you can have as many fluids there as you need.

And "hand luggage" that is included in tickets allows you one to have a small purse as addition to a small suitcase. So if there are things you'd like to have in cabin, you can put them into that small purse.

Comment: That's not necessarily true - I've occasionally been offered the chance to check hand luggage in at the "check in" desk, but only on a minority of flights. More often they give you the chance to check your baggage in at the gate, but by this point you already have to have passed security.

Comment: I think this passing and checking hand luggage can cost you more. I think AirBaltics can charge 39 euros or more.

Comment: Some low-cost airlines sometimes offer it for free if the flight is full. (Or even insist that bigger bags travel in the hold.) But as I said, you can't rely on this to solve your fluids problem, often it only happens once you're already through security.